# C - scanf string with optional int

Tags: c, string, input, scanf, stdin

I'm working on a project and I can't seem to figure out a way  how to read a string with an int that's not always there.

For example: 
I have 2 variables

```
int argument = 0;
char instruction[16];
```

And on the input is:

```
"string" 57
```

I want to put "string" in instruction and 57 in argument. This I can do with

```
scanf("%s %d", instruction, &argument);
```

Problem is that input can be without the number, i.e.

```
"string"
```

Then I'd like to put "string" in instruction and leave argument equal to 0.
But the program expects a number after "string" and won't continue until it gets it.

How can I read input from stdin when I can have 2 different types of input? I tried several solutions, but none of them worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do that by not trying to parse standard input directly. Instead you

1. Read a line of input with [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).
2. Attempt to parse that line into an integer (possibly with [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)):

   - If you succeed you have your integer.
   - Otherwise you have the original string.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate a bit more how to attempt to parse with 'sscanf'? Thank you

Comment: @TomášHorecký the man page is next stop. But bear in mind that `scanf` and `sscanf` function family all return a value: the number of items successfully scanned. If not enough items, `scanf` will stall but `sscanf` will not.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, I absolutely did not realize that the functions returned a value. I tried to quickly throw something together and it seems to be working so far.